# How to consolidate vertically data that is split horizontally in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

**What I have**: I have a lot of data that is organized in many small tables (loosely speaking, not "real" tables) that are put one after the other leaving **two** columns between one and the next one. These "tables" are all composed of **six** columns and a **variable** number of lines. The tables start from cell A1. So, for example, the first table occupies columns A to F, the second I to N and so on.

**What I need**: I need all these tables to be put one below the other to create a database exportable to statistical softwares for further analysis. The script I need should take the second table and cut (or copy) and paste it just below the first one, without blank lines in-between the two. Then proceed to the third one and paste it below the second one and so on.

I've never worked with VBA but I need something to automatise this process, as doing it by hand would take many days. I do program in C++ and R, so if you can give me some guidelines I can try to put it together in a VBA script.

Thank you very much.

Comment: what about table headers?

Comment: please show us the code you are haviong a problem with and what you have tried so far

Comment: I apologize, I'll try to produce some code, even if I'm completely new to `vba`, I was just looking for good directions to take. But I'll try to figure that out myself.

Comment: Ok, I managed to delete all empty columns, now I need a script to do this: take the columns from 4 to 6, select all non-empty cells, cut, paste to the first empty cell in column A, proceed to columns 7-9, then 10-12 and so on. If anyone has any pointer please let me know. Will keep trying.

Comment: Wilco, I suggest recording a macro that does those first steps, then modifying to suit.

Comment: I have tried, but I don't know how to make the code "soft", in not having to hardcode the range to be copied. It is always three columns, but the number of rows varies.

Comment: its difficult to help you without seeing any code nor a screenshot ( again, what about the headers of those tables )

Comment: @mehow, [here](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/939163-consolidate-many-columns-into-three.html) you can see a visual example of what I need. Thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced your table so it looks like this one

[image: reproduced table]

then I wrote the code to finish like this
[image: end]

I think this is what you are looking for, heres the code

```
Sub Main()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") ' rename sheet

    Dim i&, j&
    Dim curHead As String
    Dim nextHead As String
    For i = 1 To 3
        curHead = CStr(ws.Cells(1, i).Text)
        For j = 4 to ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            nextHead = CStr(ws.Cells(1, j).Value)
            If StrComp(curHead, nextHead, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                ws.Range(Cells(2, j), Cells(ws.Cells(Rows.Count, j).End(xlUp).Row, j)).Copy
                ws.Cells(ws.Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row + 1, i).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: It throws me "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range"

Comment: Have you changed `Sheet1` to whatever your Sheets' name is? There is a comment in the code telling you to do that :)

Comment: @Wilco is it now working as expected?